# how i can get the item Of subGroup list Through the group List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, serializable

I need to select the items in List 1, if the items SubGroup list contains a subGroup object matching the GroupName of one of the SubGroup in List2. Is this possible?

```
List<RootObject> list2= (List<RootObject>)ViewState["GroupName"];
          List<SubGroup> list1 = new List<SubGroup>();

var result = list1.Where(p => list2.Any(l => p.lblGrpName.Any(c => c.GrpName== l.SubGroup)));
```

classes

```
  [Serializable()]
  public class SubGroup
  {
      public int SubGroupCode { get; set; }
      public string SubGroupName { get; set; }
      public string Item { get; set; }
      public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
  }

  [Serializable()]
  public class RootObject
  {
      public int Code { get; set; }
      public string GrpName { get; set; }
      public string GrpImgUrl { get; set; }
      public List<SubGroup> SubGroup { get; set; }

  }
```

I want the following output in my UI.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some example data and expected result?

Comment: Your 2 code blocks are inconsistent, there is nothing as `SubGroup` in the `Subgroup` list. Are you trying to find all the `RootObjects` whose `GrpName` is in the `SubGroup` list?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer what you want to achieve - currently it is hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
//"transform" list2 into a fast searchable hashSet
var subGroupNames = list2.SelectMany(x => x.SubGroup.Select(y => y.SubGroupName)).ToHashSet(); 

//check if list1 has an entry in the hashSet
var result = list1.Where(x => subGroupNames.Contains(x.SubGroupName));
```

`ToHashSet` is an Extension method of `MoreLinq`

- https://morelinq.github.io/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/

If you don't want to use this `NuGet` package you can re-write the first statement as this

```
var subGroupNames = new HashSet<string>(list2.SelectMany(x => x.SubGroup.Select(y => y.SubGroupName)));
```

---

with your given code:

```
public string getSubGroupData()
{
    try
    {
        //Label lblGrpName = (Label)rptGroupName.FindControl("lblGrpName");
        lblGrpName.Text = "GrpName";
        var groupname = lblGrpName.Text;
        var v = ViewState["GroupName"];
        List<RootObject> list2 = (List<RootObject>)ViewState["GroupName"];
        List<SubGroup> list1 = new List<SubGroup>();
        var subGroupNames = new HashSet<string>(list2.SelectMany(x => x.SubGroup.Select(y => y.SubGroupName)));
        var result = list1.Where(x => subGroupNames.Contains(x.SubGroupName));
        Repeater2.DataSource = list2;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Try to modify it like this:

```
public string getSubGroupData()
{
    try
    {
        var groupname = lblGrpName.Text;

        List<RootObject> rootObjects = (List<RootObject>)ViewState["GroupName"];

        //get the rootObjects with the GrpName of lblGrpName.Text
        var filteredRootObjects = rootObjects.Where(x => x.GrpName == groupname);

        //get the subGroup objects of the filteredRootObjects
        var subGroups = filteredRootObjects.SelectMany(x => x.SubGroup);

        //pass the subGroups to your DataSource
        Repeater2.DataSource = subGroups;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

If the `GrpName` is unique in the `List<RootObject>` you chould also do this:

```
public string getSubGroupData()
{
    try
    {
        var groupname = lblGrpName.Text;

        List<RootObject> rootObjects = (List<RootObject>)ViewState["GroupName"];

        //get the first entry in rootObjects with the GrpName of lblGrpName.Text
        var rootObject = rootObjects.First(x => x.GrpName == groupname);

        //pass the List<SubGroup> member SubGroup of the found RootObject
        Repeater2.DataSource = rootObject.SubGroup;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AtulKushwaha - `it's not working` - isn't really a helpful comment, you have to explain WHAT isn't working, I can't help you, when I don't know the details about the problem you are facing.

Comment: this is my code:public string getSubGroupData() { try
     { Label lblGrpName = (Label)rptGroupName.FindControl("lblGrpName");
         lblGrpName.Text="GrpName";
 var groupname = lblGrpName.Text;
 var v = ViewState["GroupName"]; List<RootObject> list2= (List<RootObject>)ViewState["GroupName"];
  List<SubGroup> list1 = new List<SubGroup>();
var subGroupNames = new HashSet<string>(list2.SelectMany(x => x.SubGroup.Select(y => y.SubGroupName)));  
 var result = list1.Where(x => subGroupNames.Contains(x.SubGroupName));
  Repeater2.DataSource = list2;
               Repeater2.DataBind() }

Comment: @AtulKushwaha - Shouldn't `Repeater2.DataSource = list2;` be `Repeater2.DataSource = result;` with your code you are never using the variable `result`

Comment: @AtulKushwaha - and if that is your whole code, what about `list1` it is empty - what do you expect should happen when we filter an empty list with `list1.Where(…);` - an empty list will stay empty.

Comment: i achieved first list:public string getGrpData()
        {

            
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            string url = "http://10.3/SushilaTest/Service1.svc/GetItemWithGroup";
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
            getRequest.Method = "GET";

Comment: code contnue.............................................                     
  Request.ContentType = "jpeg/json";
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            json_data = client.DownloadString(url);


            List<RootObject> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json_data);
            ViewState["GroupName"] = list;


            rptGroupName.DataSource = list;
            rptGroupName.DataBind();
            



            return "Grpdata";

Comment: @AtulKushwaha - that seems to be the code to fill `list2` but I was talking about `list1` as your code only has `List<SubGroup> list1 = new List<SubGroup>();` - so you are only initializing an empty `List<SubGroup>` and two lines later there is a `list1.Where(…)` so still empty...